# how can i delete dynamic elements from My html page using Jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I have my code here
http://jsfiddle.net/NT4Zr/5/

In above code i am able to add new row but cant delete added row by clicking Delete link.
How can i do that?

In hobbies section i want to add hobbies by writing into text box and add hobby button and it should be reflected to label

```
        <label>Your Hobbies:</label>
```

and by clicking delete button it should be deleted.

How can i do that?

---

Please refer this link

http://jsfiddle.net/NT4Zr/28/

as it works well but when i am adding school by typing school name and selecting year it will add new elements with same name.
how can i create blank elements like this http://viralpatel.net/blogs/demo/dynamic-add-delete-row-table-javascript.html

How can i pass textbox value to the label in hobby section?

Comment: Argh. Yet another question asker who hasn't heard of `.live()`.

Comment: can you please explain it or attach some link?

Comment: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7633467/how-can-i-delete-dynamic-elements-form-my-html-page-using-jquery#7633512), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7633467/how-can-i-delete-dynamic-elements-form-my-html-page-using-jquery#7633559) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7633467/how-can-i-delete-dynamic-elements-form-my-html-page-using-jquery#7633535).

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/NT4Zr/28/   please find this link to answer my remaining question for add/delete hobby..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the element does not exist when you bind the click event, it is not associated.
You need live to bind the event to dynamic elements.

http://jsfiddle.net/NT4Zr/19/

```
$('.deleteEl a').live('click', function () {
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

event handlers do not get attached to the dynamically added elements to the DOM try using [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

```
 $('.deleteEl a').live("click",function () {
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/NT4Zr/12/)

Answer (score 1):

Working example using [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) here: http://jsfiddle.net/jkeyes/KYrAE/1/

```
$("#Education").delegate(".deleteEl a", "click", function(){
        $(this).parent().parent().remove();
});
```

[`delegate` is more efficient than `live`](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/quick-tip-the-difference-between-live-and-delegate/).